# How to create a column name dynamically? when we groupby and sum multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to dynamically create a column name with some suffix added. I can do it in for loop but I think it will be inefficient. Is there a way to do it dynamically instead.

```
from pandas import Timestamp
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': range(1,6),'A':['A','A','A','B','B'],'D':[2,3,4,5,6]})

df['C'] = [Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
Timestamp('20130102 09:00:03'),
Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')]
```

I can do it in multiple step like :

```
df['D_2days']=df.groupby('A').rolling('4d',on='C')['D'].sum().values
df['B_2days']=df.groupby('A').rolling('4d',on='C')['B'].sum().values
```

Is there a way to do it in 1 go. I have more than 1000 columns that needs to be summed and having a loop might not be a great idea.

Thank you,
Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can group and calculate rolling sum on multiple columns in on go by passing the list of column names on which to calculate rolling sum, then assign the calculated rolling sum to the columns inside a dataframe after adding the required prefix

```
c = pd.Index(['B', 'D'])
df[c + '_2days'] = df.groupby('A', sort=False).rolling('4d',on='C')[c].sum().values
```

---

```
   B  A  D                   C  B_2days  D_2days
0  1  A  2 2013-01-01 09:00:00      1.0      2.0
1  2  A  3 2013-01-01 09:00:02      3.0      5.0
2  3  A  4 2013-01-02 09:00:03      6.0      9.0
3  4  B  5 2013-01-01 09:00:05      4.0      5.0
4  5  B  6 2013-01-01 09:00:06      9.0     11.0
```

Comment: Nice.  This is why I love SO so much.    Believe it or not, this is the first time see this method using pd.Index on the left of an assignment. +1

Answer (score 4):

IIUC,

```
cols = ['D', 'B']
df.merge(df.groupby('A').rolling('4d',on='C')[cols].sum().add_suffix('_2days'),
         right_index=True, left_on=['A', 'C'])
```

Output:

```
   B  A  D                   C  D_2days  B_2days
0  1  A  2 2013-01-01 09:00:00      2.0      1.0
1  2  A  3 2013-01-01 09:00:02      5.0      3.0
2  3  A  4 2013-01-02 09:00:03      9.0      6.0
3  4  B  5 2013-01-01 09:00:05      5.0      4.0
4  5  B  6 2013-01-01 09:00:06     11.0      9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following has the potential to be used with many columns. By concatenating, we know the position of the suffixed columns and therefore we can fill them up with the rolling sum aggregation pretty handily :)

```
df = pd.concat([df, df[["B", "D"]].add_suffix("_2days")], axis=1)
df.iloc[4:]=df.groupby('A').rolling('4d',on='C')[['B','D']].sum().values
```